# How could I change my Permalink from blog to custom structure?

Tags: posts, customization, permalinks, blog

When I install multi wordpress site I have a problem that 
my default site permalink goes to

```
http://site.myurl.com/blog/post-name/
```

I want to change it so that it goes to a custom link like this:

```
http://site.myurl.com/blog/%postname%/
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Epic good edit @HoboSapiens, way to save the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do that with your permalinks. You can do what you want in **Wordpress Settings.**

1. Go to your Wordpress dashboard, 2. Click "Settings", 3. Click General. 4. In the "Site Address (URL)" Box remove the "blog" part like this --> "http://site.myurl.com/

**NOTE:  DON'T CHANGE THE WORDPRESS ADDRESS URL!!!** Only change the **Site Address**

Here is a screenshot

[image: Change Wordpress Site Address]